# Is my proof of the divergence of prime reciprocals valid

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization, divergent-series

I tried to prove the divergence of the prime reciprocals as a challenge  and I think I came up with quite an intuitive argument using Borell Cantelli, but maybe not rigorous.

For two primes $p_n>p_m$ and a large integer $N >>p_n>p_m$, the probability of the event $P(E_n)$ that that $p_n$ divides N is $1/p_n$, and independent of $E_m$ the event that $p_m$ divides N.

If we assume by means of  contradiction that the prime reciprocals do converge, than $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(E_n) < \infty $$
And by Borel Cantelona, we have that only finitely many $E_n$ happen simultaniously with probability 1. It can then be seen quite easily (or does this need further clarification)? that the probability of none of the $E_n$  must be larger than 0.  Thus there is some $\epsilon > 0$ so that for large N, the probability that no primes divide $N$ is at least $\epsilon$. That means that N is a prime with probability $\epsilon$ and thus the primes have positive natural density of $\epsilon$ , but then their reciprocals should diverge; a contradiction.

Is this a valid proof and reasoning ? Thanks for reading it!

Comment: The role of $N$ is hard to follow.  If $N$ is fixed throughout, then of course $\sum P(E_n)<\infty$ since $E_n$ is impossible as soon as $p_n>N$.  And of course only finitely many $E_n$ can occur simultaneously, as $N$ can only be divisible by finitely many primes.

Comment: "No primes divide $N$" is incompatible with "N is a prime" since primes divide themselves! In general, my critique of this argument as given is that it's unclear what the probability space is (one can't put a uniform probability on the set of all positive integers), and the Borel–Cantelli argument requires a specific fixed probability space. This argument can certainly be made to work, but we need to be more rigorous.

Comment: Wouldn't a similar proof work for the twin primes in which case the sum is however finite ?

Comment: @Peter The twin primes converge, thus big numbers are not divides by infinitely many twin primes. And there is some $\epsilon$ >0  probability that a large numbers N  has none prime twine divisors.  My proof logic uses that the primes are exactly the numbers that are not divided by primes, and that recursiveness in definition I use to set up for a contradiction